# Mulesoft - Using choice component

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-el

I'm developing an application with mule studio,
I need to use the "Choice" component, but I'd like to evaluate not a message property contained in the payload, but a variable contained in a property file, like that:

```
<choice doc:name="Choice">
                <when expression="${CONTROL_VARIABLE}.equals(&quot;S&quot;)">
                    <set-variable variableName="URL_ADDRESS" value="${URL_PREPATH_VALUE}/[#payload.URL]" doc:name="Variable"/>
                </when>
                <otherwise>
                    <set-variable variableName="URL_ADDRESS" value="[#payload.URL]" doc:name="Variable"/>
                </otherwise>
            </choice>
```

Of course it doesn't work, because if I understand properly, only message payload can be evaluated.

How can I accomplish the task in the best way?
Have I to add all the property file variables in the payload in some way?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The conditional expression in the CHOICE is going to work absolutely fine with data loaded from properties files.

try the following piece and it should work.

```
<when expression="'${CONTROL_VARIABLE}' == 'S'">
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

you can also define choice expression condition referring  to properties files as below.

`<when expression="#['${test}' =='1']">`

Answer (score -2):

You were just missing to enclose you property reference with single quote.You can also use equals method instead of using `==` operator. You just need to enclose your property reference with single quote before the comparison.

```
<*when expression="'${CONTROL_VARIABLE}'.equals('S')"*>
```

Explanation: When you enclose the property reference with single quote like '${CONTROL_VARIABLE}' it gets converted into string object after this you can apply any method/operator which supports String type.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This answer is c=very similar to the accepted answer. When answering an old question with an accepted answer please add something new and useful.